# Android and IOS backend framework choice?

Tags: android, ios, spring, mobile, spring-mvc

I'm going to development a mobile application (not mobile web application) with android and ios versions. I need a back-end server to store and process the data. So mobile application only use for present the data from back-end server.

Now questions:

1. what kind of data communication I need to use, socket or http?
2. what backend framework i can chooose, for example, spring mvc or others web development framework
   still available for mobile application ? spring does provide android spring but not for ios. Any framework has well-support for both of mobile application?
3. Is it similar with web development, if i use POST/GET for data transfer via http?

thx!

Comment: Are you looking for "just storage" i.e. each app reads/writes some data from/to the back-end DB, or do you want to have "sync" between multiple clients? I am working on a generic solution to that second case and would like to gather your requirements if you are willing to share them....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) right now to do REST for my mobile apps and it's working pretty well. You wanna use a REST paradigm because it's the most robust and resilient to network outages (which you're going to have to be very tolerant of with mobile devices). With REST and Django, you can just do all your communication over an standard Http connection, which makes your backend compatible with pretty much any platform you can think of. Django is also nice because it's in python and you can prototype things really fast. No need to write raw SQL or anything like that because of the Object-Relational-Mapper. It's really nice.

Other web frameworks you might wanna look into for your backend are: [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/), [Lift](http://liftweb.net/), [Ruby On Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), and [Pylons](http://www.pylonsproject.org/).

Comment: thank you for quick reply. so web backend framework still available for mobile app if i use http connection? ok i have not django and python. i will have a look.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a ready-made solution, you might want to have a look at [Parse](https://www.parse.com/). It's still in beta, but I've been hearing good things about it. They provide API libraries for Android and iOS.

If you are going to build it yourself, do use HTTPS to protect data in transit and use whatever framework/language you are most comfortable with.